# Property 'personal' does not exist on type 'Web3' by using web3.personal.unlockAccount()

Tags: web3js

I am using

> web3.personal.unlockAccount()

but meeting a issue

> " Property 'personal' does not exist on type 'Web3'."

what is the problem?

Comment: Can you send more details: geth or parity setup, Web3 initialisation. Thanks

Comment: Which version of web3 do you use? You can find it out with console.log(web3.version.api)

Answer (score 1):

It should be..

```
 web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(userId,password,unlockDurationInSeconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Geth, you should start it with `personal` api. `geth --testnet --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "admin,db,debug,eth,miner,net,personal,shh,txpool,web3" console`. Be careful with what you are going to expose otherwise you may make your node vulnerable for attacks. If it is for tests only, don´t worry, but if it is for production and you are dealing with serious amount of money, use it with a lot of careful.